# SQL query / number of records

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple table with two columns. The first field represents an id, the second one a name (string value). No field is unique. So, e.g., there are many records like:

[image]

What I need is a simple SQL statement which shows me the whole table in the following format and inserts the content into a new table.

[image]

Any help?

Comment: you should try it yourself first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [`COUNT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) function to count `from_id`. And if you want to count in group, use [`GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) clause for that. Like this one.

```
SELECT `name`, COUNT(from_id) AS `COUNT`
FROM myTable 
GROUP BY `name`;
```

This will return your desired result.

Now you want to insert it into new table then you can do like this:

```
INSERT INTO newTable (`name`, `count`) 
SELECT `name`, COUNT(from_id) AS `COUNT`
    FROM myTable 
    GROUP BY `name`;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `group by`:

```
insert into tab2 (name,cnt)
select name, count(1) as cnt
from tab
group by name
```

[Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) is more informations about aggregate functions.

### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/47f74/1/0) DEMO